# Explorer.exe not responding on every startup. Windows re-install and changing user account did not fix this

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1903

My dad has same problem in two of his laptops. After booting, the bottom taskbar keeps showing the "loading" circle and icons do not load properly (blank white icon).

Temporary solution has been CTRL+ALT+DEL to enter Task Manager and restart Explorer.exe.

We have tested CPU with Intel Diagnostics Tool, RAM with Memtest and SSD with CrystalDiskInfo. No hardware errors were found from those components.

We also re-installed Windows 10 from scratch. It did not help. Then we upgraded from version 1803 to version 1903. No help from that either.

Could this be some kind of Hardware error, outside of CPU/RAM/SSD since complete Windows re-install does not help?

What really confuses me is that it only happens on my dads laptops and it is the same problem.

EDIT: OK, so most likely the problem came through the synchronization settings, but the root of the problem is still unknown. However, i know that the problem showed up first on the other laptop, which in that case should be the origin of the problem.

I've disabled synchronization and i'll try upgrading Graphics drivers for both laptops.

EDIT 2: I have come to the reasoning that the problem lies somewhere in Explorer.exe or something that's connected to it since the problem solves temporarily with restarting Explorer.exe . (problem returns on next boot).

But the fact that complete re-install of Windows did not help, would suggest that the install data itself has corruption or that it becomes corrupted through some Windows-service.

Upgrading Graphics drivers did not help. `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` went through without problems, `sfc /scannow` found some corruption and repaired them, but it did not help.

EDIT 3: I tried changing the user account from MS-account to local account. It did not help.

Summary of the situation so far: Windows re-install does not help, there are no hardware problems, MS-account is not the cause either.

I am at total loss what to do next. It is like both laptops are cursed or something.

Comment: Have you tried to disable synching your settings?

Comment: @Ramhound Not yet, though that most likely explains the connection between the laptops, not the root of the problem itself.

Comment: I had a specific idea in mind with regards to the cause of the problem.